# Errors when upgrading a Grails Project Groovy\Grails Tool Suite

Tags: grails, ggts

I'm trying to run a Grails Application from [the Grails In Action website](http://www.manning.com/gsmith2/). I've imported the 'hubbub' project into the GGTS app and have encountered build errors. The project was originally built with Grails 2.3.7 whereas I have version 2.4.4 on my system. Based on [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034023/how-do-i-upgrade-the-grails-version-for-an-existing-application) I've changed the '*app.grails.version*' in the *application.properties* file to grails version 2.4.4 which prompted a flurry of downloads in the command prompt terminating in a series of errors regarding problems with plugins. I can't run the app because I'm told that "Project 'hubbub' is missing required source folder: grails-app/utils". If I try to change '*app.grails.version*' back to 2.3.7 I'm told that I need to configure a Grails installation of 2.3.7.

Am I doing something wrong here in trying to upgrade this Grails project? Or do I really have to install Grails 2.3.7 in order to get this to work?

(Sorry, I haven't posted the errors regarding plugin downloads but I can't seem to recreate them).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes Grails 2.4 is a big change over 2.3, mostly due to the use of the asset pipeline instead of resources. Also simply changing the version in application.properties isn't enough, you also need to run the matching Grails framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails 2.4 is a big change over 2.3, mostly due to the use of the [asset pipeline](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/) instead of [resources](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/).

Also simply changing the version in `application.properties` isn't enough, you also need to actually run the matching Grails framework.

See here for upgrading an app from 2.3 to 2.4: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html . From experience upgrading Grails apps from older versions must be done manually. One reason is that the `upgrade` command is obsolete and has been removed. Read the docs for breaking changes and address each change individually in the code. Upgrading patch levels are no problem (usually), but upgrading minor and major versions often are a lot of work.

Since you are learning, I would stick to 2.3.7 for your exercise (meaning that you *must* run 2.3.7, which you aren't doing). What you'll learn will remain valid. Do use 2.4.4 when building your own project from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice and installed version 2.3.7. I then received an error message regarding the Groovy compiler level, so I opened window->preferences->groovy->compiler and clicked a link about switching compilers, the link is broken tho. If I click project properties and select compiler level from there I can only select "I don't care" as a level, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If your project only missing grails-app/utils, try just to create it. 
Take a look in your Project Properties -> Build Path. There are all the source folder defined. It can be helpful